# Is there a way to create an event in mysql which should run on every first day on every month in Shamsi date not in gregorian date

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I want to add some record in a database table in every first day of every shamsi month.

The problem is that we can only set start date in gregorian as I know.
Is there a way to do this, Please let me know

Comment: There's a bunch libraries out there to convert one calendar type to another. First use them to convert your date to Gregorian form and then set up your event.

Comment: If it was me, I'd handle the conversion in application code

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I tried date conversion but again it will not get the exist day it will get one day smaller or one day bigger or may be the same day that is why conversion is not working here.

Comment: @Strawberry Could please show me a way where I could handle this senario.
Where I can add every first day of shamsi month a record in a database table

Comment: @NajlaAhmadyar What language are you programming in?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto PHP

Comment: @NajlaAhmadyar Have you seen [this library](https://github.com/morilog/jalali) on Github? Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023000/convert-jalali-calendar-to-georgian-by-php-in-codeigniter) might be helpful.